# How to right align the last line of a block of text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line, block, quotation

I’m using `pandoc` to convert a Markdown file to a LaTeX document and then to PDF. The document I have contains some quotations. Coming from standard Markdown, they are rendered as `quotation` or `quote` in the LaTeX document.

There’s no possibility in Markdown to specifically indicate a signature or attribution of the quotation. As a result, I can’t use a package like `attrib` to style the attribution part differently.

Question: how can I right align the signature of the quote? More generally, how can the last line of a block be right flushed? Or, can a line starting with "--" be right aligned? (Any of these three will do.)

Here's a minimal LaTeX document that shows my intention. I would like to have the "-- Walt Disney" part shifted right.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em} % Added for clarity.
\renewcommand{\quote}{\list{}{\itshape}\item\relax} % Making quote italic.
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
The way to get started is to quit talking and begin doing.

-- Walt Disney
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

And no, using a package like `dirtytalk`, `csquotes`, or `epigraph` will not work. The source from Markdown does not (and can not) distinguish between the quote and the attribution. It's all one `quote` block.

Comment: No, that'll not work. The source coming from Markdown does not contain a specific marker for the attribution part. It's all in the same `quote` block, and there's no way to insert some LaTeX code in the original source.

Comment: No, that'll not work either. The attribution is part of the quote block (also in the original Markdown). If I'd place the signature outside the quotation in the Markdown original, it'll be rendered as a normal (subsequent) paragraph, which isn't what I want.

Comment: @Zarko, to make my intention clear: there's no opportunity to add LaTex commands to the block in the LaTeX document. The LateX document is created from the Markdown, with no option for customizations. So, I think that the change should be make in the definition of the `quote` command, not in the `quote` block in the document.

Comment: So, indeed it can be seen as a limitation of `pandoc`, but the generic question is equally valid in a normal LaTeX document: how to align the last line of a block differently? Even forgetting the specific case of a quotation with attribution... how to change the left/right justification of just the last line of a block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you are wanting `Markdown` to be extended to have a new kind of quote. You say that "It's not the idea of a Markdown document to include style/rendering commands" but it does --- it enables specification of *italic* and **bold** fonts.

Regarding LaTeX here is a declaration (`\justlastragged`) that will set the last line of a paragraph flush right.

```
% lastraggedprob.tex  SE 641048

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\paratext}{Just some text to fill up a couple of lines,
  which might be used for a paragraph or
  some other kind of text block. Let's hope it works out.}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\justlastragged}{%
  \leftskip =0pt plus 1fil
  \rightskip =-\leftskip
  \parfillskip=\leftskip
% \parindent = 0pt
}
  
\section{First}

Normal paragraph setting

\paratext

\paratext

\section{Second}

Last line of a paragraph being set flush right (ragged left).
\justlastragged

\paratext

\paratext

\paratext \paratext

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\justlastragged` declaration is one among several settings for differently styled paragraphs that I described in TUGboat in 2007 https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-2/tb89glister.pdf

Comment: Thanks. About "It's not the idea of a Markdown document to include style/rendering commands" but it does --- it enables specification of italic and bold fonts." I meant that I didn't want to include things like `\hfill` in the Markdown source text (which is not Markdown syntax) to pass instructions just for one possible output format (LaTeX in this case).  Otherwise I would also need to include `<p style='text-align:right'>whatever</p>` for HTML output.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `\hfill` to fill in the horizontal space before `-- Walt Disney`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em} % Added for clarity.
\renewcommand{\quote}{\list{}{\itshape}\item\relax} % Making quote italic.
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
The way to get started is to quit talking and begin doing.

\hfill -- Walt Disney
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

And yes, pandoc will process `\hfill` so long as it is outputting LaTeX or using LaTeX on the backend to, e.g., produce a PDF.

```
> The way to get started is to quit talking and begin doing.
> 
> \hfill -- Walt Disney
```

[image: pandoc output]

(Image produced by pandoc; if you want it italic like your LaTeX code does, you'll have to add more to the markdown file or pandoc's options, of course, but I gather you already know how to do that?)

Comment: Thanks. That'll work for `Markdown -> LaTeX -> PDF` but not if I'm using `pandoc` to create other output formats based on the same Markdown. Isn't there a better way to right align the last line of a block without inserting LaTeX-commands in the source?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't understand what the big deal is. I understand you might want to use the same markdown file elsewhere and thus not use LaTeX commands in them, but surely you can preprocess the markdown before passing to pandoc. `sed 's/^>\s*--/> \\hfill --/' filename.md | pandoc -f markdown -o filename.pdf` or whatever. Besides pandoc will just ignore the `\hfill` for something like html output.

Comment: Thanks. That'll work, although I dislike to include all kinds of formatting directives in a source document (that I can filter out in some cases if I don't want them to end up in other formats). It's not the idea of a Markdown document to include style/rendering commands.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately I don't know of a better way; maybe someone else will.